# JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly -- mvn

Tags: java, maven

Ran a mvn clean install and got:

```
konnor@konnor-laptop:~/workspace/automation$ mvn clean install
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /opt/jdk/bin/java
```

I've done a little research on this and haven't found out how to resolve, anyone have any thoughts?

Some additional info:

```
konnor@konnor-laptop0:~/workspace/automation$ which java
/usr/bin/java

konnor@konnor-laptop:/opt/jdk$ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr 18 08:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr 18 08:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 18 08:52 bin
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr 18 08:51 jre
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 18 08:52 man


konnor@konnor-laptop:~$ /opt/jdk/bin/java -version
bash: /opt/jdk/bin/java: No such file or directory


konnor@konnor-laptop:~/workspace/automation$ $JAVA_HOME
bash: /opt/jdk: Is a directory
```

Comment: what is in `/opt/jdk/`? It looks like it `/opt/jdk/bin/java` isn't the Java executable

Comment: added ls -la of that dir

Comment: I can't read that. Add it to your post please. Also output the result of `/opt/jdk/bin/java -version`. Just want to work out whether that is actually a JDK.

Comment: Added what you requested :)

Comment: That seems to be the issue. In a full Java JDK there should be a `java` executable in `bin`. You seem not to have that. I would wipe the directory and unzip the JDK to that location again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would download the .bin file of Oracle JDK 1.8.0_05  and then unzip it to  /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05  .  Then, do what you can to attach it to your PATH using  'alternatives --install blah blah' for setting up the default Java on your system.